# Let $U$ be an $m \times n$ matrix where the columns of $U$ form an orthonormal set

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

> Let $U$ be an $m \times n$ matrix where the columns of $U$ form an orthonormal set.
>
> a) If $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ are in $\mathbb{R}^n$, show that $(U\vec{x})*(U\vec{y}) = \vec{x} * \vec{y}$
>
> b) Show that $\|U(\vec{x})\| = \|\vec{x}\|$

I'm very confused on how to do this exactly. I'm looking for a non-calculus approach since this is a [Linear Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra) class.

Comment: Compute the Gramian $\mathrm U^T \mathrm U$.

Comment: For part $a)$ or for part $b)$ @RodrigodeAzevedo

Comment: For both. Use the definition of the Euclidean norm, too.

Comment: @Yusha Not a single answer here involves calculus. o.0  They're all just basic linear algebra (inner products, norms, etc).

Comment: I know it's not what you're looking for, but I'd be interested in finding an approach that used calculus.  That would be impressive.

Comment: Since when are Summations not calculus lol?

Comment: Since ... always?

Comment: I never learned about summations until Pre-Calculus and Calculus 1 lol, but I'm checking out the answers provided now

Comment: Just to help with that, the *definition* of the standard inner product on $\Bbb R^n$ (also called the dot product) is $\vec x \cdot \vec y = \sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i = x_1y_1 + \cdots + x_ny_n$.  This is a question involving the standard IP, thus the summations.  You'll also see a vector $\vec v$ expanded in the basis $\{\hat e_i\}$ written as $$\vec v = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i\hat e_i = v_1\hat e_1 + \cdots + v_n\hat e_n$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume you are working with the field of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$.  Let $\{\vec{u}_1,\ldots,\vec{u}_n\}$ denote the columns of $U$, i.e.,
$$U=\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{u}_1 & \vec{u}_2 &\cdots & \vec{u}_n
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Write
$$\vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\\vdots \\x_n
\end{pmatrix},
\qquad \vec{y}=\begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_n
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then we have
$$(U\vec{x})\cdot (U\vec{y})=\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\vec{u}_k\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{k=1}^ny_k\vec{u}_k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nx_ky_j\vec{u}_k\cdot\vec{u}_j=\sum_{k=1}^nx_ky_k=\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}.$$
(Minor adjustments needed here to account for complex scalars).  Using this, the answer to part (b) is simple.

Comment: How can I get part b? Because I'm getting $\sum_{k = 1}^n x_k = \vec{x}$ when I should be getting $||\vec{x}||$ right?

Comment: Just use part (a) and the definition of the norm:  $\|\vec{x}\|=\sqrt{\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}}$.

Answer (score 0):

In principle already said by Rodrigo, but writing it out (we need $m\geq n$):
$$\sum_{i=1}^m U_{ij} U_{ik} = \delta_{j,k}, \ \ \ 1\leq j,k\leq n.$$
And then (omitting limits on the sums): $$\langle Ux,Uy\rangle = \sum_{ijk} U_{ij}x_j U_{ik}y_k= \sum_{jk} x_j \delta_{j,k} y_k = \sum_j x_j y_j = \langle x,y\rangle.$$

Comment: Just to clarify -- because OP uses the dot notation -- $\langle x,y\rangle$ means the same thing as $\vec x\cdot \vec y$.  Also $\delta_{j,k}$ is the row $j$, column $k$ element of the identity matrix (so $1$ if $j=k$ or $0$ if $j\ne k$).